# Unable to save form data to database in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am building a Spring MVC application where someone can fill up the form and if clicks Send then form data will save in database. I am using spring-data-jpa. But when I fill up the form and click send it shows HTTP Status 500 error. I followed every steps but its not working. Here is my Contact model, Contact service and Contact repository and the error --->
Error::::

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
type Exception report
message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.save(Unknown Source)
    com.learningspring.service.Impl.ContactServiceImpl.saveMail(ContactServiceImpl.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.saveMail(Unknown Source)
    com.learningspring.controller.ContactsController.submitContactForm(ContactsController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:79)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:432)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:765)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.persist(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.save(Unknown Source)
    com.learningspring.service.Impl.ContactServiceImpl.saveMail(ContactServiceImpl.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.saveMail(Unknown Source)
    com.learningspring.controller.ContactsController.submitContactForm(ContactsController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table'learningspring.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:216)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:138)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:432)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:765)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.persist(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.save(Unknown Source)
    com.learningspring.service.Impl.ContactServiceImpl.saveMail(ContactServiceImpl.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.saveMail(Unknown Source)
    com.learningspring.controller.ContactsController.submitContactForm(ContactsController.java:40)
```

Contact Model::::

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "website")
    private String website;

    @Column(name = "subject")
    private String subject;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    Getters and Setters ...
}
```

ContactServiceImpl class::::

```
@Service("contactService")
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    @Qualifier("contactRepository")
    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Contact saveMail(Contact contact) {

        System.out.println("Inside Contact Service impl");

        return contactRepository.save(contact);

    }
}
```

ContactRepository Class::::

```
@Repository("contactRepository")
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long> {

}
```

I noticed that in Contact model, I noticed table name is not resolved. some problem with datasource.[image]

Here is my persistence.xml:::

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="punit">

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and Jpa-config.xml:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.learningspring" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.learningspring.repository" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/learning?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="learning" />
        <property name="password" value="learning" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl" value="none" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

and web.xml where I configured jpa and dispatcher servlet:::

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/jpa-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>learningspringServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>learningspringServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the error stack trace?

Comment: Also, I don't see entity class `Contact` referenced in `persistence.xml`!

Comment: As you are using Spring-Data-Jpa you didn't need persistence.xml anymore. You just need to indicate to your entitymanager where to find entities to manage. I will post you an answer showing how well configure that.

Comment: can you paste the log trace ?

Comment: i have edited the post and attached error stack trace. please have a look at it

Comment: yes I am using spring-data-jpa. I also added hibernate-entitymanager. Is there a chance that those will conflict when configuring jpa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As promise, here how you could configure your project. Spring-data is a really nice tool which prevents from old-school processes.

Let's assume that your entities are in this package : `org.myproject.entities` This is the package where the `EntityManager` will look up entities to persist. And your respositories interfaces here : `org.myproject.repositories`

So in your Jpa-config.xml you'll have :

```
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="org.myproject.entities"/> <!--Your package(s) here-->
<!--Other configs-->
</beans:bean>
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.myproject.repositories"/> <!--You should add "jpa" namespace-->
```

Now you can delete your `persistence.xml` and remove your the annotation `@Repository("contactRepository")` (all interfaces in the 'org.myproject.repositories' package will be scanned and added in the bean's container).

In the web.xml try :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:jpa-config.xml</param-value><!--Is it Jpa-config.xml or jpa-config.xml?-->
</context-param>
```

**EDIT :**
Try a new datasource configuration using a connection pool. E.g. try using BoneCP.

Dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Configuration in jpa-config.xml

```
<beans:bean id="poolingDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" >
    <beans:property name="poolName" value="giveTheNameYouWant"/>
    <beans:property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/learning?useSSL=false&amp;?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;?autoReconnect=true&amp;?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
    <beans:property name="user" value="learning"/>  
    <beans:property name="password" value="learning"/>
    <!--...There are lot of properties that you can config-->
</beans:bean>
```

Then

```
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="poolingDataSource"/>
<!--.... -->
</beans:bean>
```

Let us know...

Comment: Thank you for giving me your valuable time. Yes I did what you have suggested. I deleted persistence.xml and removed @Repository annotation and added `<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.learningspring.model" />` and also in the web.xml but still getting that error. I have attached the error. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Don't use '@GeneratedValue()' alone without some attributes value. Try '@GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)'

Comment: I already tried that but didn't work. I think this problem is with the data source. Datasource is missing somehow. Because when I went to persistence tab to Assign Data Source which I found at View->Tool Windows->Persistnce. But Datasource is present there, so I don't understand, why this problem is showing. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: `@generatedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)` is to avoid this exception : `
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table'learningspring.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist`
I edited my answer, try configure a new dataSource and let us know ...

Comment: OMG it worked bro. Thanks for taking time to help guide me. Though I have a few question.

Comment: 1) I used the previous database connection once before and then it worked. But this time it didn't, is there a problem with the version that I used?
2) In Contact entity, the problem that stated "Cannot resolve table 'contacts' " exist still no. How it's happening yet though I have a working datasource. Can I ignore this message now?

Comment: Javadoc of Spring's DriverManagerDataSource class says  `Useful for test or standalone environments outside of a J2EE container...`. So it worked before because it was a standalone application. 2) Check your database, if the table was created or not, if not create it manually (you can also drop this table, re-run your app and let hibernate create it for you).

Comment: Thanks alot @akuma8 you saved my life, it's worked for me after adding @generatedValue(strategy=IDENTITY) , previous i am using AUTO.