# Unable to Save Form Data Using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have gone through this: [Unable to save form data to database in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200018/unable-to-save-form-data-to-database-in-spring-mvc) but did not solve what my issue is. Now, i created two entities. One(Expensegroup) is to be used as a dropdown for the other(Expenses). But anytime I tried to save, it generate this error:

```
   Field error in object 'expense' on field 'expenseGroup': rejected value [3]; codes [typeMismatch.expense.expenseGroup,typeMismatch.expenseGroup,typeMismatch.com.pebnic.financemgr.entity.ExpenseGroup,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [expense.expenseGroup,expenseGroup]; arguments []; default message [expenseGroup]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pebnic.financemgr.entity.ExpenseGroup' for property 'expenseGroup'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.pebnic.financemgr.entity.ExpenseGroup' for property 'expenseGroup': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]].
```

***See the Entity- ExpenseGroup:***

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tab_expgroup")
public class ExpenseGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="code")
    @NotNull(message="Expense Group Code is required")
    @Size(min=3,message="Expense Group Code must be minimum of 3 Characters")
    private String code;

    @Column(name="name")
    @NotNull(message="Expense Group Name is Required")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="flag")
    private String flag;
```

getters & Setters

**Expense Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tab_expenses")
public class Expense {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="item")
    private String item;

    @Column(name="expense_date")
    private String expenseDate;

    @Column(name="amount")
    private double amount;

    @Column(name="narration")
    private String narration;

    //Foreign Key Mapping
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="expensegroup_id")
    private ExpenseGroup expenseGroup;
 Getters & setters


**Controller:**

@GetMapping("/showForm")

public String showFormAdd(Model theModel) {

Expense theExpense  = new Expense();

List<ExpenseGroup> theExpenseGroup  = expenseService.getExpenseGroupList();

theModel.addAttribute("expense", theExpense);

theModel.addAttribute("expenseGroups", theExpenseGroup);

return "expense-form";

}


@PostMapping("/saveExpense")

public String saveExpense(@ModelAttribute("expense")Expense theExpense) {

expenseService.saveExpense(theExpense);

return "redirect:/expense/list";

}
```

**DAOImplementation:**

```
@Override

public void saveExpense(Expense theExpense) {

Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theExpense);

}
```

**See the Form:**

```
form:select path="expenseGroup" class="form-control">

<form:option value="">Select the Category</form:option>

<c:forEach  items="${expenseGroups}" var="grp">

<form:option value="${grp.id}">${grp.name}</form:option>

</c:forEach>

</form:select>
```

This is the output of the form above:

```
<select id="expenseGroup" name="expenseGroup" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select the Category</option>

<option value="1">Beverages</option>

<option value="3">Cooking</option>

<option value="6">Self Development</option>

<option value="2">Grains</option>

<option value="5">Personal Allowance</option>

<option value="15">Self Training</option>

<option value="4">Utility</option>

</select>
```

Issue: Anytime I try to save, it throws the error of rejected value,no matter what options I select.How can i resolve this,so to save/persist the data, knowing that i am persisting the data using Hibernate Query Language of calling saveorUpdate function.I am new to Spring and hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Use one-to-one (mappedBy) in expense model  and use same name as  join column name in Expense group model.

Comment: I used one-to-one JoinColumn in expense model  and i didn't define any relationship in expenseGroup, since expenseGroup is just data entering which is rather static. So could this be the issue?

Comment: Please, i am new to it, just practising, can you modify the line of code for me to see it, how it should be on both sides. please

Comment: It is now throwing another error: 500. See remapping of entity, perphaps i am making mistake: Entity Model: //Foreign Key Mapping
 @OneToOne
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="expensegroup_id")
 private ExpenseGroup expenseGroup;   while ExpenseGroup Model:@OneToOne(mappedBy ="ExpenseGroup")
 private Expense expense;                                    and the form has been changed to expenseGroup.id

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. Still not working.Now throwing error around mappedBy

Comment: Note that expenseGroup.id is not a field, hence will this not throw an error?

Comment: This has still not work. Is there a better way of achieving this result?

Comment: Set groupId in request model. 
Then find 'group' by selected group id.
ExpenseGroup group = expenseGroup.find(selectedGroupId);
 set group into expense object and then save. 
expense.setGroup(group);
expenseRepo.save(expense);